# Calculate, next latitude

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

I am pretty new to Lat/ Long calculations. I am trying to calculate the next latitude and longitude. Given the distant to travel, direction (heading) and current lat/ long.

This is what my formula looks like in JS:

```
function nextLat(lat, brng, d) {
    var clat = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat)*Math.cos(d/R) + Math.cos(lat)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng.toRad()) );
    return clat;
}
```

Where:
lat - current latitude
brng - is the direction
R - Radius of the Earth in kms
d - Distance traveled

This input Lat is: 25.30977055
I except a value of 25.313055555555557, but what I get is: 0.1810335115243139

My inputs are in Radians. I have been scratching my head, without a real clue at to what I'm doing wrong.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming that the traveler is moving along a geodesic, or is the traveler moving with a constant bearing?

Comment: I am calculating the new bearing every time.

Comment: Look for the section "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" at this website: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html   It has a calculator you can use to check your work.

Answer (score 0):

For a short distance, If you can assume that the geodesic and constant bearing are the same thing, then the answer is:

```
clat = lat + sin(brng) * d/R
```

Where brng = 0 is east, 90 is north, 180 is west, 270 is south.

For longer distances, presumably the person is traveling along a geodesic.

Comment: I just have the start and end co-ordinates, how do I decide if the person is travelling north, south east or west?

Comment: This website looks pretty good. http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm There are formula in there for an intermediate point along the route, and there is a formula for finding bearing given two points. The former should give you the lat you are looking for. And the latter if you plug in the intermediate point and the end point, will give you the bearing.